# Is it possible to enable a Firefox addon using a terminal command on the mac?

Tags: terminal, firefox

Is it possible to enable and possibly even configure a Firefox addon using terminal?

Every now and then I need to temporarily disable an addon.  I often then forget to re-enable it but it is really important I keep it running as often as possible.  I thought that if I can enable the addon through a terminal command then I can run that command on a timer somehow.

*(please be kind, I'm still new to the mac!)*

Comment: `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --help` "  --safe-mode        Disables extensions and themes for this session."

Comment: thanks @anki that looks promising. I need to enable my extensions them but maybe there is something here

Comment: I couldn't find anything about enabling a specific one. Instead you can run that "*Every now and then I need to temporarily disable an addon.*" mode with the above flag. Every new session will have the add-on anyway. Otherwise, remember the shortcut cmd + shift + a

Comment: No, it is not possible to enable/configure arbitrary add-ons using Terminal, see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options for more information on available command line options. Note that this restriction is not specific to the Mac.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is create a new [Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles?redirectslug=profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles&redirectlocale=en-US).

That profile will be completely different from the default profile that you normally use including the add-ons that are installed.

Command line Mac Command Line Options:

#### Symlink the Firefox binary (optional)

The Firefox binary is located in `/Applications/Firefox.app/Conents/MacOS` so I suggest making a symlink to it so you can launch Firefox from anywhere and you don’t have to type out the full path each time.

```
% sudo ln -s /Aplications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

For the rest of the examples below, I will assume that the binary is symlinked.  If you chose not to, you’ll need to type out the full path.

#### Launch Firefox Profile Manager

The ProfileManager launches Firefox with a Profile selection box in the GUI allowing you to choose which profile you’d like to use

```
% firefox -ProfileManager
```

#### Create a Profile

This is the quick command to create a profile in the default location which will be in the `~Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles`  directory.

```
% firefox CreateProfile <profile name>
```

To create a profile in a specific directory, you need to specify either the absolute or relative path

```
% firefox CreateProfile “profile_name profile_dir”
```

#### Launch Firefox specifying a profile

This command will launch Firefox with a specific profile

```
% firefox -P “<profile_name>“
```

Use this command if you have Firefox already running and want to have a new instance with a different profile

```
% firefox -new-instance -P “<profile_name>”
```

Comment: Thanks @Allan, this creates a new profile. I see what you're getting at but it doesn't really solve the problem as even on the new profile my user may end up disabling the addon.  Also, to further complicate matters there is an activate addon as a setting inside the addon!  So I do indeed need to change the settings of the addon.

Comment: If that’s not something that the folks at Mozilla makes available via their CLI, then there’s nothing we can do to address your issue as you describe. All we can do is propose a workaround

Comment: The other problem is in your question: you say “I need to do X” and in this comment, you say “I want to prevent the *user* from doing Y” which completely changes the context of the question.  You can manage what add-ons can/can’t be installed via policy with Firefox in Enterprise mode. That, however, is a very different question from the one you asked.

Comment: That's a fair point, thanks for your help @Allan